# Как с помощью скрытого тега <input type="hidden"> передать переменную методом GET в скрипт php?

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Я новичок в веб-разработке. Пытаюсь на странице создать таблицу произвольного размера с помощью языка html и php. Мне нужно скрыто хранить размер таблицы и по нажатию кнопки увеличивать или уменьшать его. Написал сам код по прорисовке таблицы и он работает отлично, но не получается передать туда переменную с размером таблицы. И именно не получается вед суперглобальный массив GEt пуст. Использую такой код.

```
<html>
   <body>
       <form  method="GET">
           <input type="hidden" name="size" value="10">
       </form>
       <?php include 'php/test.php'; ?>//файл в котором прорисовывается таблица


   </body>
</html>
```

Предлагайте и другие варианты хранения скрытой переменной. Буду рад если ещё дадите советы по созданию кнопок для уменьшения и увеличения размера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### page.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form  method="GET" action="page.php">
            <?php
                if( isset( $_GET['size'] ) ) {
                    $size = $_GET['size'];
                } else {
                    $size = 3;
                }
                if( isset( $_GET['inc'] ) ) {
                    $size++;
                } else {
                    if( isset( $_GET['dec']) && ($size > 1 ) ) {
                        $size--;
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?=$size?>">
            <input type="submit" name="dec" value="Уменьшить">
            <input type="submit" name="inc" value="Увеличить">
        </form>

        <?php 
            include 'table.php'; 
        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

### table.php

```
<table>
<?php
    global $size;
    for( $i = 1; $i <= $size; $i++ ) { 
        echo "<tr>";
        for( $j = 1; $j <= $size; $j++ ) {
            echo "\n<td>Ячейка $i:$j</td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
<style>
    table,td {
        border:1px solid grey;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Да с кнопкой всё работает. А можно как-то чтобы при заходе на страницу оно сразу отправлялось а потом по нажатию кнопки? Тоесть захожу на стр у меня сразу таблица 3х3 строилась?

Comment: Я бы просто явно задал в php значение по умолчанию, когда нет GET.

Comment: ```<?php
 $size  = isset( $_GET['size'])  ? $_GET['size']  : 3;
?>
```

Если именно при загрузке страницы, то тут только JS поможет

Comment: Изменил ответ, добавил вариант реализации кнопок увеличения и уменьшения.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` пустой из-за того, что форму надо отправлять (submit), чтобы хранить переменную, которая изменяется от клиента, можно применить следующую тактику:

1. Вы формируете отдельный JS скрипт, который считывает событие изменения размерности таблицы (`change` input-а) и передает через `ajax` значение;
2. Скрипт-обработчик принимает значение через `$_GET/$_POST` и формирует html код таблицы и отдает его обратно JS скрипту;
3. JS скипт получает ответ с html кодом таблицы и рисует ее.

Другой вариант - изменить форму вашу на `<form  method="GET" action"/">`. В action прописываете путь страницы, где будет отображаться таблица. Добавляете обязательный `<input type="submit">` либо на JS делаете `submit` формы по нажатию на кнопку. Тут возможно перегрузка страницы.

Советую использовать первый метод - куда лучше решение.

Comment: Большое спасибо, понял свою ошибку а можете по подробнее рассказать про 1 метод.

Answer (score 0):

Твоему скрипту доступен глобальный массив $_GET с параметрами, просто укажи в форме параметр action.

```
<html>
   <body>
       <form  method="GET" action="/">
           <input type="hidden" name="size" value="10">
       </form>
       <?php 
         global $size; 
         $size = $_GET["size"]; // используй $size для размерности
         if (!$size) $size = 10; //значние по умолчанию
         include 'php/test.php'; ?>//файл в котором прорисовывается таблица

   </body>
</html>
```

Но лучше для этой задачи использоваить JS.

Answer (score 0):

В странице оптравки :

```
<form  method="GET" action="send-data.php">
       <input type="hidden" name="size" value="10">
       <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
   </form>
```

В странице получателя (send-data.php):

```
<?php echo $_GET['size'] ?> //тут печатается 10
```

Если захотите пробовать POST то просто замените все слова GET на POST во всех страницах